# Can some Lie groups ($S^3$ in particular) be converted to simplicial groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I'm trying to understand the concept of Kan simplicial sets and simplicial groups in particular. My question is, in a nutshell:

> What is the relation between the group operation in a simplicial group
>   and the (possible) underlying topological group structure?

For example, Eilenberg-MacLane spaces have a natural simplicial group model, but I don't know whether this correspond to a group operation on the underlying topological space. Does it?

Conversely, can Lie groups be converted into simplicial groups (in a more feasible way than applying the singular ss functor)? I was thinking about $S^3$, the group of unit quaternions. As far as I know, a simplicial set describing $S^3$ up to homotopy type is its Postnikov tower, build as a twisted product of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces, but what about the group operation? Can it be defined so that it reflect somehow the group operation in $S^3$ (at least "up to homotopy" in some way that I cannot formalize yet)?

Comment: The singular simplicial set functor takes topological groups to simplicial groups.

Comment: @ZhenLin Right. But can anything more feasible be done, at least for $S^3$? Thank you

Comment: That's a bit broad. In full generality there isn't really a "more feasible" approach to turn a topological space into a simplicial set. Do you really want a simplicial model for $S^3$ (in which case you should probably clarify the question), or an approach that works for every topological group?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for your comment. For $S^3$ in particular and for $(S)O(n)$ if possible. I will appreciate any hint...

Comment: Well to be perfectly honest I'd really like to know a simplicial group model for $SO(n)$! So far the best I could come up was to take a simplicial model of $BSO(n)$ and then a simplicial model for $\Omega X$ (since $SO(n) \simeq \Omega B SO(n)$), but that's horrible...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The simplicial model for $BSO(n)$ is known? Could you give me a reference please?

Comment: Well that's the thing, I'm not even sure what a simplicial model for $BSO(n)$ is, I found some answers on MO (e.g. [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/q/124342/36146)) but I didn't delve in detail.

Comment: Yes, I know that link. As far as I understand, nobody even knows how to triangulate $Gr(2,4)$...